Is it possible to use Clang Code Completion instead of Intellisense in Visual Studio 2022?
My main IDE at work is Visual Studio 2022, but sometimes I use Android Studio or XCode. I've realized that the code completion and/or reference finding works much better in both Android Studio and XCode than Visual Studio. I assume it's because they use Clang as their engine for code-completion tasks.
Is it possible to change the underlying engine in Visual Studio 2022 to use Clang?

This is impossible. And you are mistaken, you get different completion results because of different SDKs.

No, I get different results because Intellisense freezes up all the time and does not find anything.

Intellisense is awful, even when it is working I find it to be a distraction, maybe because I learned to code before intellisense was available. Just turn it off.

I disagree, Intellisense increases my productivity by a factor of 10, when it works...

If you set up a Clang configuration, will the underlying engine change?

I've tried that, but it seems it still uses regular Intellisense for auto-completions, find references etc. (Clang works great for debugging though, totally seamless)

I guess his feature is not currently supported . I would suggest you to raise  a feature request at Developer Community.That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
